# Borel sigma algebra are generated by open sets

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Please check my proof:

The Borel sigma algebra $B(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is generated by all (left) half-open intervals. I need to show that it is also generated by all open intervals:

So $(a,b)=\bigcup(a,b-1/n]$
so $(a,b)$ is in the Borel set generated by half open intervals.

Similarly $(a,b]=\bigcup(a,b+1/n)$ hence $(a,b]$ is in the Borel set generated by all open intervals.

Comment: I think you are looking at $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ (1 dimensional).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you mean $(a,b] = \bigcap (a, b+1/n)$ (rather than $\bigcup$) which is indeed in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open intervals. Besides this typo, you're entirely correct!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you just one more question: How can we say in the first part that since $(a,b)$ can be written as a countable union of half-open sets this implies that the Borel algebra of open sets is also generated by half-open sets?

Comment: You're going the other direction. We know that every borel set can be written in terms of the open sets $(a,b)$. So since we can write $(a,b)$ in terms of the half open sets $(p,q]$, this means we can _also_ write every borel set in terms of the half opens. Indeed, just write it in terms of opens $(a,b)$, then write each $(a,b)$ as a union of half opens. You can think of this as showing a certain set $\mathcal{C}$ of vectors is spanning by writing every basis vector in terms of vectors in $\mathcal{C}$.